# SSL certificate for weird domain

Tags: firebase, ssl, ssl-certificate, firebase-hosting, namecheap

I use firebase hosting for my website and it created an SSL certificate for me. And my website is seen as secure. But now I checked and the certificate is for a domain I don’t know called “www.cheesusburger.at”.
Why is it not for the name of my website?
It says that it’s by “Let’s Encrypt Authority X3”.
Also now I noticed that the default firebase provided app domains have a different certificate. I use namecheap for my custom domain. So is namecheap responsible for the weird SSL certificate?

Thank you

Comment: Don't look just at the subject of the certificate, look at an extension called SAN for Server Alternative Names and you will find a whole bunch of names there.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Hosting by default uses a shared certificate from Lets Encrypt. While your domain name propagates, it is normal that your browser may show the site as not secure. This should resolve itself as your domain propagates, which typically happens within a few hours.

If you don't want to use a shared certificate, have your own certificate ready to go, and your project is on the Firebase Blaze plan, you can [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to get your site with your own certificate.

Comment: Wow thank you. I will see what I can do.

Comment: One more question if that's okay. My project is on Spark plan. I have bought an SSL certificate from namecheap but I need something called a CSR. Do I get that from firebase? I couldn't find it.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but from https://www.sslshopper.com/what-is-a-csr-certificate-signing-request.html it seems like that would come from Firebase. It might be worth to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for this, as they know better than I do. As said though: your project will need to be on the paid/Blaze plan for using your own certificate.

Comment: Thank you. Was able to get CSR and everything. Now I'm just trying to find out how to install an ssl in firebase